# Password never expires Powershellscript

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I'm looking to create AD-Users with Powershellscripts. But I'm not aware, how to create a new User whose Password never expires.

This is my example:

```
New-ADUser -Name Max -GivenName Maximilian -Surname Muster -UserPrincipalName max.muster@domain.com -AccountPassword (Read-Host -AsSecureString "AccountPassword") -PassThru | Enable-ADAccount
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the New-ADuser with the -PasswordNeverExpires parameter.
Also, if you use the -Enabled Paramter on the New-ADuser cmdlet the account is created as Enabled (this saves you from running the Enable-ADAccount cmdlet).